# How can I correctly check for effective read/write access to a file using Windows API?

Tags: c++, winapi, acl, file-permissions

I've attempted to do this using `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`, but it's not returning the correct access mask for files that are denied to me due to a group I'm part of.

For example, I have a file, `unreadable.txt`. If I deny write access to `unreadable.txt` for my current user, the access mask correctly shows that I don't have write access. However, if I instead deny write access for the 'Authenticated Users' group, the access mask implies that I have full access (which I don't).

My alternative was to manually iterate the Ace list and compare my SID with each entry, but I'm unable to find a clean or easy way to check if the Ace is for a group, and if the current user is part of that group.

As an extension, the file may not exist (i.e. it's a new file, about to be written), in which case the access to the directory needs to be checked.

Is there any good solution to this? It seems like there should exist an easier way to do this, without actually trying to read/write to the file in question.

Comment: Denying for a group won't necassarily deny a member of that group if there are other permissions/ACLs that are overriding it.

Comment: I was under the impressiont hat more specific (user rights) override less specific (group rights). I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [AccessCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead, as recommended by the knowledge base article on the [Limitations of the GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl API](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262278).

Answer (score 1):

Just try to open the file with the desired mode using [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) - if it succeeds you know you have the access rights. You don't actually have to write anything to the file, just close it right away.

Comment: The file may not exist, in which case it's up to the containing folder. I should have clarified this.

Comment: This can create race conditions making for a flaky user experience, if another app tries to access the file at the same time. I've had plenty of unwelcome experiences where I can't edit or delete files because some app held them open transiently.